# Unable to move multiple sprites in an array - SpriteKit - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, sprite-kit, nsmutablearray

I am trying to create an endless scroller. The walls will all spawn from the right of the screen in exactly the same position but at different times.

I am having an issue where I can not move all my walls in my array. I am able to make one single wall move but if I attempt to move multiple generated walls in an array it fails. Could somebody please have a look at my code and give me an indication of where I am going wrong?

Thanks in advance!

### GameScene.m

```
@interface GameScene() {
Wall* brickWall;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *wallArray;
- (void)generateWall {

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {

 brickWall = [Wall node];
 brickWall.zPosition = 2;
 brickWall.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.frame) * 1.1, CGRectGetHeight(self.frame) * 0.3);
 [self.wallArray addObject:brickWall];
 [self.wallArray addObject:brickWall];
 [self addChild:brickWall];
 }


-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {

if (self.gamePlaying == YES) {

    for ( brickWall in self.wallArray) {
         brickWall.position = CGPointMake(brickWall.position.x-4, brickWall.position.y);
    }




}

}
@end
```

### Wall.m

```
@interface Wall () {
SKSpriteNode* brickWall;

}

@end

@implementation Wall

-(id)init {
if (self = [super init]) {
    // do initialisation

    brickWall = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"BrickWall"];
    [self addChild:brickWall];



}
return self;
}
@end
```

Comment: You only seem to create one sprite object.  Also what's with the instance variables?

Comment: @trojanfoe

Apologies, there is some code that is running a repeating sequence.
`[self runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever: [SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction performSelector:@selector(generateWall) onTarget:self], [SKAction waitForDuration:2]]]] withKey:@"CreateWall"];`

Also what do you mean by your question "...what's with the instance variables?" Is there something bad about the way I am doing it?

Comment: Yes; look at the `for` loop in the `update:` method; you are assigning each element of the array to the instance variable. This should be a local variable.

Comment: Why are you adding brickWall two times to the array?

Comment: I've figured it out now. Thanks @trojanfoe.

Comment: @Stefan, that second line shouldn't be there.